# Does complement of a set is closed imply the set is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I gave a test on topology. On seeing the checked paper, I saw that the professor has deducted my marks for writing this in an intermediate step:-

"$A^c$ is closed implies $A$ is open."

I even asked this since I feel it follows from the definition of a closed set. He has defined a closed set as follows :- A set $A$ in a topological space $X$ is closed if its complement is open.

But he says my argument is wrong.

I don't know what am I overlooking.

Please clarify.

Comment: You could ask the professor?

Comment: @Gitika He doesn't want to clarify why your argument is wrong?

Comment: That is not a good answer, so either you misunderstood, or the professor is wrong.

Comment: Well, that's false and so basic it's hard for me to believe someone teaching topology would say that.

Comment: @JustinYoung..nothing..I just thought I shouldn't share the conversational details here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becoming extraordinarily pedantic, $A^{c}$ closed implies $A^{cc}$ is open and then show that $A^{cc} = A$.

Comment: Hmm, even though you are right, I'm surprised that this argument was expected when dealing with topological spaces. Elementary set theory shouldn't be a required step.

Comment: @Gitika are you sure this is what your professor was looking for?

Comment: Other than showing $A^{cc} = A$,there is nothing wrong with your argument.